# Deleted comment

Tags: discussion, comments

I'm curious as to why my comment in the question:

["Is it wrong to buy a Buddha statue in Thailand from a Buddhist point of view?"](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/8485/is-it-wrong-to-buy-a-buddha-statue-in-thailand-from-a-buddhist-point-of-view)

was deleted. I can think of a number of reasons. Maybe it was considered *ad hominem* (I mentioned I thought people were too hard on the answerer), or perhaps the reflection was nonsense or misleading.

It would help to know what I'm doing wrong here to have some feedback. It would be nice to get feedback rather than things just disappear, but either way, feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[The answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/8497/18) on which you commented was deleted by the poster of said answer. As a result, all comments to the answer were deleted. That's just how it goes :)

Comment: Thank you yuttadhammo . As you say, the way it goes. It is quite hard to go from most of SE, which is quite a boisterous place, straight to here in one click: I worry that I fail to notice the tone sometimes.

Comment: np... btw, you don't have to put an @ tag in a comment to a post by the @ person... they get pinged anyway. It's only for if you want to ping others (including other commenters).